# Error filtering in SAPUI5 data type not allowed

Tags: sapui5

I am adding multiple search filters in my Query App, but the fields of type SAPB1.BoYesNoEnum of the Metadata of the services layer, throw me an error when filtering.

**EntitySet BusinessPartners property**

```
<Property Name="Valid" Type="SAPB1.BoYesNoEnum"/>  = tYes/tNo
```

**Filter event:**

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
    var oFilterModel = this.getView().getModel("filters");

    var sID = oFilterModel.getProperty("/id");
    var sName = oFilterModel.getProperty("/name");
    var sStatus = oFilterModel.getProperty("/status");
    var aFilters = [];

    if( sID ) {
        aFilters.push( new Filter("CompanyName", FilterOperator.Contains, sID.toUpperCase()) );
    }

    if( sStatus ) {
        aFilters.push( new Filter("Valid", FilterOperator.EQ, sStatus.toUpperCase()) );
    }

    this.byId("idPartnerTable").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
},
```

*The other filters, ID, Name, work perfectly*

**Console Error**
Failed to get contexts for /destinations/miruta/BusinessPartners with start index 0 and length 5 - Error: Unsupported type: SAPB1.BoYesNoEnum

Comment: Hi, I hope you are passing values 'N' or 'Y' in the BoYesNoEnum filter!!!

Comment: @Piyushaggarwal yes im passing values Y or  N, but console error is  Error: Unsupported type: SAPB1.BoYesNoEnum